# How in Elisp regexp match text after a newline?

Tags: regex, newline, elisp

I have a string like

```
str="?tag0
1,2,3
4,5,6
?/tag0"
```

and I want to replace `\n?/tag0` with `?/tag1?/tag2?/tag0` like

```
str="?tag0
1,2,3
4,5,6?/tag1?/tag2?/tag0"
```

like

```
(setq s (replace-regexp-in-string "[ \n\t\r]*\?/tag0" "?/tag1?/tag2?/tag0" str))
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` means zero or more of the preceding pattern. So this will match at the beginning since there are zero newlines before `?tag0`.

Use `+` instead to match one or more of the pattern.

And to put a literal `\?` in the regexp, you need to escape the backslash.

```
(setq s (replace-regexp-in-string "[ \n\t\r]+\\?/tag0" "?/tag1?/tag2?/tag0" str))
```

Comment: I don't know the reason but this not match the string. I only mach with "[\n].\?/tag0" but i can not mach more \n than one.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash in `\?`. I've updated the answer and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq s (replace-regexp-in-string "[ \n\t\r?/]*tag0" "?/tag1?/tag2?/tag0" str))
```

Comment: This replaces `?tag0` at the beginning, which isn't in the desired result.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.